# How to add form capture from Microsoft Dynamics in a SPA app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, microsoft-dynamics

We are using **React in a SPA**. When we use a form of a page without navigation **Microsoft Dynamics form capture** works fine. But if we come from another page that has a form and we navigate via React-router to another page that has another form, then the form stops working. How can we solve this? I think is related to SPA applications.

This is the component that adds the script to MS Dynamics:

```js
const SOURCE = '...SOURCE...'; // ..../public/latest/js/form-loader.js?v=1.84.2007
const WEBSITE_ID = '...WEBSITE_ID...';
const HOSTNAME = '...HOSTNAME...';

let alreadyLoaded = false;

export default function MSDynamicsForm() {
  useEffect(loadDynamics, []);
  function loadDynamics() {
    if (alreadyLoaded) return
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = SOURCE;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    alreadyLoaded = true;
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="d365-mkt-config"
      style={{ display: 'none' }}
      data-website-id={WEBSITE_ID}
      data-hostname={HOSTNAME}
      data-no-submit="true"
    />
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the `useEffect` clear method:

- Remove script
- Remove injected code in `window`
- Remove injected `iframe` from MS Dynamics

Now is working fine, loading from scratch the script navigating to another page:

```js
export default function MSDynamicsForm() {
  useEffect(loadDynamics, []);
  function loadDynamics() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = SOURCE;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.childNodes[0]);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
      // @ts-ignore
      window.MsCrmMkt = undefined;
      const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src*="dynamics.com"]');
      if (iframe) iframe.remove();
    };
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="d365-mkt-config"
      style={{ display: 'none' }}
      data-website-id={WEBSITE_ID}
      data-hostname={HOSTNAME}
      data-no-submit="true"
    />
  );
}
```

However, it is not a very elegant solution. If anyone has a better answer, you are welcome.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Incase it's useful, I also needed to add my form block id div to the render as well `<div data-form-block-id="..."></div>`. I wrapped this and your div in ` <>...</>` as there was now 2 divs at the top level.

Comment: Any ideas how to use the events like `MsCrmMkt.MsCrmFormLoader.on("afterFormLoad")`?